# Groupby Filter unique to Group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Performing a filter within groupby and encountering trouble. The filter is for the elements within each dataframe of the groupby; unique to that dataframe of the groupby.

I want to groupby the first df on ID, then return a df filtered for the values on a condition shown in conditions_df. That condition is associated with the same value as the first groupby.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,3,3], 
                   'V': [0,1,1,0,1,1]})


condition_df = pd.DataFrame(index = [1,2,3], data= {'Condition': [0,1,1]})
```

I'd like to see a data frame returned:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,3], 
                   'V': [0,1,1,1]})
```

This does not seem to work.

```
df.groupby(['ID']).filter(lambda x: x['V'] == condition_df.loc[x.index, ['Condition']])
```

Even simplifying without that lookup in condition does not seem to work.

```
df.groupby(['ID']).filter(lambda x: x['V'] == 0)
```

Both return a

> "TypeError: filter function returned a Series but expected a scalar
>   bool"

Totally open to alternative methods of accomplishing the same complex filtering task!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You're trying to get filter the dataframe to show only the rows that match the condition, where the condition_df index matches `ID`?

Comment: I want to find the values of V equal to the condition unique to the ID in condition_df

Answer (score 0):

Join in your conditions, then filter:

```
df = df.join(condition_df, on="ID")
df[df["V"] == df["Condition"]]
```

Result:

```
   ID  V  Condition
0   1  0          0
2   2  1          1
4   3  1          1
5   3  1          1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `merge`

```
df.merge(condition_df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'ID','Condition':'V'}),how='inner')
Out[831]: 
   ID  V
0   1  0
1   2  1
2   3  1
3   3  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
df.merge(condition_df.reset_index(), left_on=['ID', 'V'], right_on=['index', 'Condition']).drop(['index', 'Condition'], 1)
```

Output:

```
ID  V
0   1   0
1   2   1
2   3   1
3   3   1
```